# Использование ICQ через GTalk

Tags: icq, google-talk

Хочу настроить icq через google talk. Поискал, нашел много инструкций по прикручиванию транспортов icq. Скачал Psi, подключился к серверу гугла, но не могу получить список сервисов (service discovery) ни с одного стороннего сервера. Зарегистрировался на gojabber.org; если зайти на него, service discovery работает. Если на talk.google.com - нет. В чем дело? Гугл закрыл поиск сервисов?

UPD: Одна из инструкций здесь: http://tiaurus.ru/1236.
Смущает то, что все инструкции старые (2007-2008).

Comment: А использование клиентов вроде QIP, Miranda, qutim, pidgin вас не чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: Устраивает. Если вам нечего сказать по делу - проходите мимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Гугл закрыл поиск сервисов?

У гугла просто нет никаких сервисов :).

Ведь чтобы пользоваться транспортом не обязательно, чтобы сервис транспорта был поднят на *Вашем* джаббер-сервере (т.е. в данном случае у гугла). Подключите транспорт с любого другого сервера.

Comment: Смотрите комментарий к предыдущему ответу.

Comment: Пинайте свой клиент. У меня работает. В том числе, нашёлся транспорт на сервере с Вашего скрина.

Comment: http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/8/2/upload/9bfc6d9e.png

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы эта штука работала, надо чтобы на вашем jabber-сервере был требуемый транспорт.

Вы можете подключиться к jabber через google talk и искать сервисы на любом сервере, но не все сервисы вам доступны для использования. В частности, насколько я понимаю, транспорты не могут быть использованы в таком раскладе.

Comment: Так дело именно в том, что я не могу даже искать сервисы, соединившись через сервер google talk.
Вот скрины:
Gtalk: http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/9/8/upload/69694786.jpg
Другой jabber-сервер: http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/a/9/upload/8b868a8f.jpg

Поиск по одному и тому же адресу, но через сервер gtalk ничего не видно.